# How do I close a Tkinter window and retain a StringVar value?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am having a couple issues with the following code:

1. After the radio button is selected and the OK button is selected, the Tkinter window does not close.  I have tried various methods to close the Tkinter window - `quit()` and `destroy()` both inside `buttonAction()` and after `master.mainloop()` - but neither has worked. The code will run endlessly and the window does not close.
2. The `compGDB` variable assignment is not retained after the code is run. At this point, I'm wondering if the `compGDB` variable isn't retaining simply because the destroy/quit code failure.

---

```
import Tkinter, getpass
username = getpass.getuser()

def buttonAction():
    compGDB = choice.get()
    print compGDB
    #master.quit()
    #master.destroy()

vwrMinGDB = "C:\\Users\\" + username + "\\Desktop\\ViewerAttribution\\Viewer_minimum.gdb"
fullGDB = "C:\\Users\\" + username + "\\Desktop\\ViewerAttribution\\Full_geodatabase.gdb"

master = Tkinter.Tk()
master.title("Schema comparison")
master.geometry("250x100")

choice = Tkinter.StringVar()
choice.set(vwrMinGDB)

chooseOption = Tkinter.Label(master, text="Slect geodatabase for schema comparison")
rButton1 = Tkinter.Radiobutton(master, text="Viewer Minimum Attribution", variable=choice, value=vwrMinGDB)
rButton2 = Tkinter.Radiobutton(master, text="Full Geodatabase Attribution", variable=choice, value=fullGDB)
confirmButton = Tkinter.Button(master, text="OK", command=buttonAction)

chooseOption.grid(column="1", row="0")
rButton1.grid(column="1", row="1")
rButton2.grid(column="1", row="2")
confirmButton.grid(column="1", row="3")

master.mainloop()
#master.quit()
#master.destroy()
```

Thanks, y'all!

Comment: This works just fine for me, using the `master.destroy()` that's inside `buttonAction()` - are you sure you haven't stripped down your code past the point where it actually exhibits the problem?  Calling `.quit()` just exits the mainloop without closing any window; any code after `.mainloop()` won't get executed at all until you've already called `.quit()` or destroyed the window.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Jason.  I swear I tried the block of code independent of my larger script and it didn't work.  But now it is working fine alone.  Weird, but okay...I'll take it. Ha!  
So I put it back in it's place within the larger script I was working on and it started having issues again.  It turns out it was because earlier in the larger script I had created a different type of Tkinter window that I never quit or destroyed.  Once I added in a destroy for the first Tkinter window, my radio button works perfectly.  
This is my first time using Tkinter so thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your first issue.  You can `quit()` by calling `master.quit()` within `def buttonAction():`, there should be something else missing.

Your second issue though, it is because `compGDB` is [*locally created*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces) within the function `buttonAction`, so once the function is done the attribute ceases to be.

While the better advice is to rebuild your code as a `class` and define `compGDB` as an *instance/class attribute* (so you can recall it as long as the class instance is still in memory), you can see it can be a bit of work.  An easy workaround (IMO not best practice) would be:

```
compGDB = ''

def buttonAction():
    global compGDB
    compGDB = choice.get()
    master.quit()
```

So that this way, the *global* attribute `compGDB` is still retained and you can recall it anywhere even after `master.mainloop()`.

But again, consider using an OOP approach for your `tkinter` if you have use for the information afterwards.  It'll help maintain your namespace easier especially for complex scripts.

Comment: Thanks for the knowledge and quick workaround!  The script and Tkinter windows are at least functioning now.  I will look into the OOP approach too. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

For the second issue: Retain a variable after `tkinter` window is closed with `destroy()` I implemented the OOP approach r.ook suggested. I took some furhter inspiration for this approach from https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-object-oriented-window/.

In my example a filepath is retained after the window is closed, but it could be any variable.

```py
from fileinput import filename
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog


class tkApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.filename = ""

        # Config root window
        self.title('Select a file to plot.')

        # Buttons
        self.my_btn = tk.Button(self, text="Select File", command=self.open_fileselect).pack()
        self.my_btn2 = tk.Button(self, text="Quit", command=self.destroy).pack()

        self.tk.mainloop()

    def open_fileselect(self):
        self.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir=r'C:\Users\some_dir',
                title="Select A File", filetypes=(("excel sheets", "*.xlsx"),("all files", "*.*")))
        self.myLabel= tk.Label(self, text=self.filename).pack()
        self.my_img_label= tk.Label(self,text="Test").pack()
        self.data_filepath = self.filename

# Create class instance. This will automatically run tkinter, since the mainloop call is included inside the class.
my_App = tkApp()

# Retrieve the variable from the class instance
print(my_App.filename)
```